# Get which trace was clicked

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have two histograms and want to get which bar the user clicked. The problem is that the click event returns all points that are in the same interval of histogram.

Is there a way to get which trace was clicked?

The assumption here is the existence of layers in bars, so if the user click somewhere both bars exists, the system would return the bar of the top layer.

```js
var x1 = [];
var x2 = [];
var y1 = [];
var y2 = [];

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv')

for (var i = 1; i < 500; i++) 
{
 k=Math.random();
 x1.push(k*5);
 x2.push(k*10);
 y1.push(k);
 y2.push(k*2);
}
var trace1 = {
  x: x1,
  y: y1,
  name: 'control',
  autobinx: false, 
  histnorm: "count", 
  marker: {
    color: "rgba(255, 100, 102, 0.7)", 
    line: {
      color:  "rgba(255, 100, 102, 1)", 
      width: 1
    }
  },  
  opacity: 0.5, 
  type: "histogram", 
  xbins: {
    end: 2.8, 
    size: 0.06, 
    start: .5
  }
};
var trace2 = {
  x: x2,
  y: y2, 
  autobinx: false, 
  marker: {
         color: "rgba(100, 200, 102, 0.7)",
          line: {
          color:  "rgba(100, 200, 102, 1)", 
          width: 1
    } 
    }, 
  name: "experimental", 
  opacity: 0.75, 
  type: "histogram", 
  xbins: { 
    end: 4, 
    size: 0.06, 
    start: -3.2

  }
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {
  bargap: 0.05, 
  bargroupgap: 0.2, 
  barmode: "overlay", 
  title: "Sampled Results", 
  xaxis: {title: "Value"}, 
  yaxis: {title: "Count"}
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function (data) {
  alert(data.points.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```